# How does spring instantiate a bean from a annotated interface (e.g. JpaRepository)?

Tags: java, spring, interface, javabeans, autowired

I'm currently using Spring for a project, and I'm confused how Spring can actually instantiate an annotated interface such as a `JpaRepository`.

As far as I know, an interface cannot be instantiated without an implementation. Also it was in my understanding, that any annotations in interfaces are not inherit to the implementing class (Which should render them useless?)

So how is Spring able to actually get a working bean out of only a annotated interface as below?

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ExampleEntity, Long>{

}
```

Comment: Spring Data generates JDK proxies at runtime.

Comment: As per their homepage *As a developer you write your repository interfaces, including custom finder methods, and Spring will provide the implementation automatically.*  see [home page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)

Comment: @chrylis I'm not really familiar with the proxy concept. As I understand, spring detects the `Component` annotation and creates a default bean implementing the defined repository interface?

Comment: As mentioned by @chrylis, spring generates JDK proxies at runtime. A good way to "see that" is to run your application in debug mode and put breakpoints on the interface methods. You'll be able to see the classes generated.

Comment: @HerrDerb Read some tutorials on the JDK proxy feature. It's a core part of a lot of frameworks that provide magic, including Spring, JPA providers, REST clients, and more.